# How can I concatenate initial part cell 1 with all of cell 2 and finish with cell 1’s remainder?

Tags: excel, concatenation

## Problem

In Excel I have three columns with names for old governmental areas. These have been standardised to show the main name for the area and the old name in separate columns. Now I would like to display their full name automatically in a separate column using `concatenate` or any other suitable function.

The layout is as such:

- List item
- Col. E: Official name of area
- Col. F: Old name for area
- Col. G: Full name for area, as printed on original document. This contains what I desire for the concatenation.

It is a problem that some names have a genitive-s added to them, as shown in the example below:

```
     E                              F           G
2    Hobøl Thinglag                 Hobøle      Hobøl (Hobøle) Thinglag
8    Vaalers Thinglag                           Vaalers Thinglag
5    Rygge Thinglag                 Ryggihof    Rygge (Ryggihof) Thinglag
60   Skjebergs Thinglag             Skjaberg    Skjebergs (Skjaberg) Thinglag
108  Spydebergs Thinglag            Spjoteberg  Spydebergs (Spojteberg) Thinglag
220  Skedsmo og Nittedals Thinglag              Skedsmo og Nittedals Thinglag
```

## What I’d like to do

I need to identify the first part of the name in col. E, add what’s in col. F (if anything) in parentheses, and then add what’s left from col. E. Some form of `left` function seems appropriate, but I do not know how to identify the end of the word when not counting number of symbols.

It could be that a `right` function is more appropriate, as exemplified by row 220; there potentially are areas that some time before this document was created were joined to form one governmental areas; the separator, as can be seen, would be ‘ Thinglag’ (with the space). In other words, *the first part of cell 1 (E2:E) could contain more than one word which needs to be transposed.* Using row 220 above as an example, if there was an entry in F220 (let’s say ‘Skeidsmo og Nøttedal’), G220 should read ‘Skedsmo og Nittedals (Skeidsmo og Nøttedal) Thinglag’.

An example formula to be inserted into F2:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT[word in E2];" (";F2;") "; [the rest of E2])
```

Comment: `LEFT(E2, SEARCH(" ",E2,1))` will return the first word in E2 if separated by a space.

Comment: What does the `E2, 1` part do? Could this be rewritten as per my edit above, to work with `right` instead?

Comment: `SEARCH()` has a syntax like `SEARCH( substring, string, [start_position] )`. It returns the starting index of a match it found in the string.

Comment: The following formula worked for me in Excel 2013 (provided the 2 words in E2 are separated using a space) 
`=CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2, SEARCH(" ",E2,1)),"(",C2,")",RIGHT(E2, SEARCH(" ",E2,1)+1))`

Comment: This function almost solves the problem: `=IF(F122="";E122;CONCATENATE(LEFT(E122;SEARCH(" Thinglag";E122;1));"(";F122;")";RIGHT(E122;SEARCH(" Thinglag";E122;1))))` It does, however, yield some strange results here and there. In row 108 (E: Skibthveits Thinglag; F: Skygthveit) I got ‘Skibthveits (Skygthveit)its Thinglag’ instead of the desired ‘Skibthveits (Skygthveit) Thinglag’; in row 115 (E: Spydebergs Thinglag; F: Spjoteberg) I got ‘Spydebergs (Spjoteberg)gs Thinglag’, not Spydebergs (Spjoteberg) Thinglag’; row 122 (‘Askims  Thinglag’, Askheim’) yielded ‘Askims (Askheim)hinglag’,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF(F2="",E2,CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2))&"("&F2&")"&MID(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2),Len(E2)-SEARCH(" T",E2)+1)))
```

It first checks that `F2` is populated to see whether the strings need to be concatenated, then if they do it does the following:

1. Finds the position of the first space plus ‘T’ in `E2` using `SEARCH(" T",E2)`
2. It uses this information to extract the first word in the string using `LEFT(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2))`
3. The first word is concatenated with the brackets and value of `F2` using `&"("&F2&")"&`
4. The remaining words of the string in `E2` are obtained using `MID(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2),Len(E2)-SEARCH(" T",E2)+1)` which locates the position of the first space plus ‘T’ in the string and gets the rest of the words that follow after it.

Comment: Thank you! It does seem to do the trick. To accomodate place names such as Skedsmo og Nittedals Thinglag, I changed it to the following: `=IF(F243="";E243;CONCATENATE(LEFT(E243;SEARCH(" T";E243))&"("&F243&")"&MID(E243;SEARCH(" ";E243);LEN(E243)-SEARCH(" ";E243)+1)))` Note my inclusion of `CONCATENATE`. I edited your answer to include concatenation and the adjusted search key to match the edit to my question.

Comment: I am now trying to use the same function for a different cell. The structure is the same, but I now have to search for one of four different words: ‘Sogn’, ‘Hovedsogn’, ‘Annex’ or ‘Præstegjeld’. I tried to change the formula so it now reads `CONCATENATE(LEFT(P22;SEARCH(OR(" So";" Ho";" An";" Pr");P22) […]`, but got a too many arguments error message. Do you have any insight to share on this?

Comment: Should I post my comment above as a separate question? It does seem to be an unnecessary duplication.

Comment: Yes, if you are still stuck and have another question you will need to create a new post.