# Concatenate part of cell 1 by multiple criteria with all of cell 2, finishing with cell 1’s remainder

Tags: excel, search

## Introduction

This is a continuation of the question posted and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553995/how-can-i-concatenate-initial-part-cell-1-with-all-of-cell-2-and-finish-with-cel), but has been advised to be posted as a separate question by @Jordan.

Goal: Join part of cell 1’s contents with all of cell 2’s, finishing with the remained of cell 1.
Twist: Multiple criteria have to be applied to cell 1.

## Problem

After successfully altering Jordan’s excellent answer to accomodate concatenated names for joined *Thinglag*, the following function will perform the task, as long as there is only a single criteria to identify:

```
IF(F2="",E2,CONCATENATE(LEFT(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2))&"("&F2&")"&MID(E2,SEARCH(" T",E2),Len(E2)-SEARCH(" T",E2)+1)))
```

However, for parishes and annexes, multiple criteria are needed, vz. the following:

- Sogn
- Hovedsogn
- Annex
- Præstegjeld

## Structure

- AB–AH: Sogn_anx_[1–7]
- AI–AO: Sogn_anx_[1–7]_altnvn
- AP–AV: Sogn_anx_[1–7]_hele

As with the original post, I have a source giving current official names for the area, as well as previously used names (providing etymological information for the current name). In the source, where the old name is included, it is given as a paranthetical remark, e.g.:

- ‘Søndeløvs (Sundaleid) Annex’
- ‘Tromø (Thrumø) Annex’
- ‘Hvitesø (Hviteseids) Hovedsogn’
- ‘Attraa (Attrod) Hovedsogn’
- ‘Thjølings (Thjodaling) Sogn’

These have been entered into the database using three columns:

- One for the official name
- One for the old name
- One showing the name as printed

This is to allow for better searchability when this information is to be made publicly available.

### Example data:

```
Sogn_anx_1          Sogn_anx_2      Sogn_anx_3          …   Sogn_anx_1_altnvn   Sogn_anx_2_altnvn   Sogn_anx_3_altnvn   …   Sogn_anx_1_hele                  Sogn_anx_2_hele           Sogn_anx_3_hele
AB                  AC              AD                  …   AI                  AJ                  AK                  …   AP                               AQ                        AR
Soleims Hovedsogn                                       …   Solheims                                                    …   Soleims (Solheims) Hovedsogn
Meleims Annex                                           …   Medelheims                                                  …   Meleims (Medelheims) Hovedsogn
Holdens Hovedsogn   Romenæs Annex   Holdens Hovedsogn   …                       Rumenæs             Hollen              …   Holdens Hovedsogn                Romenæs (Rumenæs) Annex   Holdens (Hollen) Hovedsogn
```

As can be seen, the first set of columns contain the official name; the second set of columns (`altnvn` = `alt_name`) contains the old name, which in the source is written as a paranthetical remark; and the third set of columns contains the full, concatenated name (`hele` = `entire`/`whole`), which—in those cases where there *is* an alternative name—includes this in parentheses.

## Desired result

I would like to perform the same task in the third column as done in the post referenced, only this time it has to be able to perform the search by looking for any of the four criteria, so `" T"` would have to be replaced by all four variants: `" So"`, `" Ho"`, `" An"` or `" Pr"` (note: spaces are intentional). I have tried editing the original function using `OR`, but this—to no surprise—fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be simpler with a VBA solution.  But your immediate problem, to find one of several defined words using `SEARCH`, can be accomplished by using an array constant for `find_text` and appending the terms to `within_text`.  If you are not guaranteed that `find_text` will always appear, you'll need to check that the result is less than the length of the original `within_text`.

You might also consider using the case-sensitive `Find` function, or longer `find_text` strings in case there might be some ambiguity.

```
=MIN(SEARCH({" So"," Ho"," An"," Pr"},AB3&" So Ho An Pr"))
```

Comment: Where in the function should this be pasted? I am guessing it should replace all instances of search, but I suspect this is incorrect.

Comment: @CannedMan You can use this wherever you want to return the location of a substring; and the substring can be one of several choices.  I thought that was what you meant when you wrote *... perform the search by looking for any of the four criteria ...*.  If I have misunderstood, I will delete my response.

Comment: I don't think there was a misunderstanding. It's just that when I tried your function, it only returned ‘1’, instead of returning the concatenated name, as exemplified by columns AP:AR. I don’t understand why I got that result.

Comment: @CannedMan The function, like any search function, returns a location and not a string.  If the function is returning a `1`, then, most likely, the cell reference is pointing to a blank (empty) cell. Check the precedents.

Comment: Nope. I tried copying all the data into a new sheet, pasting your function and replacing all the commas with semicolons (which I did the previous time too), but I get the following results: AP3: 8; AQ3: 1; AR3: 1;
AP4: 8; AQ4: 1; AR4: 1;
AP5: 8; AQ5: 8; AR5: 8

Comment: The desired results would have been: AP3: Soleims (Solheims) Hovedsogn; AQ3: [null]; AR3: [null]; AP4: Meleims (Medelheims) Annex; AQ4: [null]; AR4: [null]; AP5: Holdens Hovedsogn; AQ5: Romenæs (Rumenæs) Annex; AR5: Holdens (Hollen) Hovedsogn.

Comment: @CannedMan **THE FUNCTION RETURNS A NUMBER**

Comment: @CannedMan The `8` means that  ` Hovedsogn` starts in the eighth position of the string.  Where the function returns a `1`, there may be a space at the beginning of the tested cell, followed by one of the substrings listed. OR there may be no match at all.  You will need to test for that.  IOW, you need to assume that `1` is an invalid response.